# Find the sum of n terms of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Given is the sequence $S[i]=(i-1)%9+1$, that is
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\dots$$
Also given are three numbers $a$, $d$ and $n$.

The task is to find the sum of first $n$ terms starting from $S[a]$, separated by $d$ terms in between.

For example, for $a=8$, $d=1$, $n=5$, the sum will be $8+1+3+5+7$.

Comment: If the first and last terms are $a_1$ and $a_n$ and total number of terms is $n$,their sum is-$\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$.

Comment: Your example is quite unclear....

Comment: See, the first term will be 8 and we want to find the sum of next five terms separated by 1 term in between.  So the terms in the sum will be 8, 1, 3, 5, 7.

Comment: So,you want the first term to be fixed and the next ters in a repeating sequence?

Comment: Yes. The next `n-1` terms should be separated by `d` terms in between each two terms of the sum.

Comment: Your first comment would have been correct had this been an arithmetic progression. But this is not.

Comment: Before posting an answer I would like to ask if this answer seems acceptable.....find the sum of all numbers from the second position (the group which is in a sequence) and then add it to the first term....Is it acceptable?If yes I would post a detailed answer..

Comment: I don't understand your approach completely, but if it works for the example case posted in the question then it is acceptable (can't think of a wrong approach that would give a right answer only in that case).

Comment: Why do you think it is not an arithmetic progression?The second term onwards is in the form of an arithmetic progression with common difference $1$...

Comment: What about the term after `9`?

Comment: You have not given the complete series...is it of the form $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.....$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I thought it was obvious from the dots in the question.

Comment: Sum of first $n$ natural numbers =$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$....Multiply it by the number of times the series repeats....

Comment: Could you please post an answer that conforms to the given numbers `d` and `n`? I am not asking for the sum of first `n` natural numbers. Try your approach on the example case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31257/discussion-between-anukul-sangwan-and-tatan).

Comment: I think that your sequence is defined in the following way: Let $A=\{1,2,\cdots,9\}$
Then $b_n=r$ if $n$ is congruent to $r (r\in A$) modulo $9$. You want then the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_{a+k(d+1)}$. A way to do this is to compute the number $N(r)$ of $k$ $0\leq k\leq n-1$ such that $a+k(d+1)$ is congruent to $r$ ($r\in A$) modulo $9$, then your sum is $\sum_{r\in A}rN(r)$. But this seem not simple to do.

Comment: I am also thinking about it in the same line as @Kelenner said. I must say it's an interesting question though.

Comment: Check out this cool property of the series. The series repeats itself after every 9th term (the period is 9). For example for a = 8 , d = 1, the series is : 8,1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6, 8,1,3,5,... . So if you are trying to write a code for this problem (which I guess you are. I think this is one of the codechef questions from November contest - https://www.codechef.com/NOV15/problems/KFUNC), you can solve this in O(1) using this property.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a sketch of one approach.

For each $i^\text{th}$ number in your sequence ($i=0$ for the first term), define $g_i = \lfloor \frac{i}{9} \rfloor$.

Given a term (say $t_i$) in your original sequence, let $T_i = t_i + 9 g_i$. This produces the familiar sequence of positive integers, for which you can work out the modified sum (say $S$) in the usual manner.

Given the set of selected $i$, you can then calculate $G = \sum 9 g_i = 9 \sum g_i$, which I'll leave as an exercise for you.

Your original sum would then be $S - G$.

---

Here's an example with $a=3, d=1, n=5$ (first index is 2, last index is 10) :

$$
\begin{matrix}
i   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10  \\
g_i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1   \\
t_i & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2   \\
T_i & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11
\end{matrix}
$$

We now calculate $S$:
$$S = \sum_{j=0}^{4} (3 + 2j) = 3 \cdot 5 + 2 \sum_{j=0}^{4} j = 15 + 2 \cdot \frac{4 \cdot 5}{2} = 35$$

We also have $i \in \{2,4,6,8,10\}$, and calculate $G = 9\sum g_i = 9 \cdot 1 = 9$.

So the required sum is $S-G = 35 - 9 = 26$.

(Check using the original $t_i$: $3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + 2 = 26$.)

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Could you please include an example?

Comment: @AnukulSangwan Ok, I've added a simple example for you.

Comment: I don't know if this is because I'm new to the math stack exchange, but this is very poorly explained. :|

Comment: @AnukulSangwan Which part do you consider to be poorly explained?

Comment: What exactly is S?

Comment: $S$ is the sum of the modified sequence. The modification changes your recurring sequence into a normal arithmetic progression, and $G$ keeps track of the difference between the sums of the two sequences. In essence, this approach changes a hard problem (sum of a sequence that may increase and may decrease) into two easier problems: sum of an AP (called $S$) and sum of a monotonically increasing sequence (called $G$). Then the difference $S-G$ gives you the original sum you wanted.

Comment: What is the modified sequence? You've expressed S as a summation of a sequence whose term is 3+2j, but I don t see any sequence of that form.

Comment: The modified sequence is $T_i$ and the first 11 terms are listed in the bottom row of the table in my example. It is just the sequence of natural numbers starting with 1. That is, $T_i = i+1$.

Comment: Why is S the summation of 3+2j?

Comment: It's because we're starting with $i=2$ and moving up through $4,6,8,10$. The corresponding $T_i$ are $3,5,7,9,11$, which can be written as $(3+2j)$ for $0 \leq j \leq 4$. (There was an error with $a$, which I've corrected. I've also added brackets to the first summation in the calculation of $S$.)

Comment: Why are we starting with $i=2$ and moving up the way we are? Also, how did you come up with the limits to the summation and the number of terms in each sequence? I think it is probably $n*(d+1)$ but it would definitely help to have this mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Please re-read the answer. It comes in two parts - a general approach, where $i$, $t_i$, $T_i$, etc are defined, then a concrete example (as you requested), with particular values for the variables. In the table (part of the example), the left column contains the variable names, and the other columns contain corresponding values for those variables - that is, pick any $i$, and the corresponding $g_i$, $t_i$ and $T_i$ are below it.

Comment: How have you calculated $S$? Which terms of $T$ did you choose and how did you choose them?

Comment: Congratulations on finding a solution. In mine, the $i$ simply tells you which term you're up to (e.g. at the zeroth term, $i=0$; at the fifth term, $i=5$). The selection of $i$ is given by your problem. E.g. for your own example of $a=8, d=1, n=5$, since $a=8$, that means your first $i$ is $7$ (i.e. $a-1$). You go up in 2s because $d=1$, so you select $i$ to be $7,9,11,$ ... in turn. You have 5 terms because $n=5$, so the instances of $i$ selected are $7,9,11,13,15$. In my example, $a=3,d=1,n=5$, so the instances of $i$ selected are $2,4,6,8,10$.

Comment: $S$ is the sum of the simple AP consisting of $T_i$ where $i$ is selected as per my previous comment.

Comment: I found $S$!. Its $n*a+(d+1)*n*(n-1)/2$, right? One last thing, could you help me determine $G$ without having to go through the whole list of $i$?